# I used Koa js for backend and React js for frontend. Routers are not working properly

Tags: javascript, koa

I tried implementing a student management system using koa js for the back-end and react for the front-end. Below I have given the controller, model, route, and utils of my Koa backend. I used react js for the front end. I used the latest versions of dependencies for both the front end and the back end. The app is compiling successfully. But the problem is data is not saved in the MongoDBcompass. I didn't use MongoDB Atlas as the DB. I used the compass. I can't find any error. In the react app update course function is not working. But the rest of the code is implemented correctly. Once I checked the back end through the Postman. It was perfectly fine. POST, GET, PUT, and DELETE requests worked for the course function. after connecting the front end also worked properly.But when it comes to the student functionality it didn't fetch the data. After connecting the front end the issue came up. Can anyone please find out the issue?

**dbConnect.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dbConnect = () => {
  const dbConStr = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

  mongoose.connect(dbConStr, () => {
    console.log("Database connected");
  });
};

module.exports = { dbConnect };
```

**index.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const Koa = require("koa");
const KoaRouter = require("koa-router");
const cors = require("@koa/cors");
const bodyParser = require("koa-bodyparser");
const json = require("koa-bodyparser");
const { dbConnect } = require("./utils/dbConnect");
const courseRoutes = require("./routes/course.routes");
const studentRoutes = require("./routes/student.routes");

const app = new Koa();
const router = new KoaRouter();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(json());
app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());
app.use(courseRoutes.routes());
app.use(studentRoutes.routes());

router.get("/", (ctx) => {
  ctx.body = { message: "Student Management API" };
});

app.listen(9000, () => {
  dbConnect();
  console.log(`Server is up and running on http://localhost:9000`);
});
```

**student.router.js**

```
const KoaRouter = require("koa-router");
const {
  addStudent,
  getStudents,
  updateStudent,
  deleteStudent,
} = require("../controller/student.controller");
const router = new KoaRouter({ prefix: "/student" });

router.post("/add", addStudent);
router.delete("/:studentId", deleteStudent);
router.put("/:studentId", updateStudent);
router.get("/", getStudents);

module.exports = router;
```

**course.router.js**

```
const KoaRouter = require("koa-router");
const router = new KoaRouter({ prefix: "/course" });
const {
  addCourse,
  getCourses,
  updateCourse,
  deleteCourse,
} = require("../controller/course.controller");

router.post("/add", addCourse);
router.delete("/:courseId", deleteCourse);
router.put("/:courseId", updateCourse);
router.get("/", getCourses);

module.exports = router;
```

**student.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  nic: { type: String, required: true },
  age: { type: Number, required: true },
  courseId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false, ref: "courses" },
});

const Student = mongoose.model("students", StudentSchema);

module.exports = Student;
```

**course.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  courseName: { type: String, required: true },
  courseFee: { type: Number, required: true },
  students: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: false, ref: "students" }],
});

const Course = mongoose.model("courses", CourseSchema);

module.exports = Course;
```

**student.controller.js**

```
const Student = require("../models/student.model");
const Course = require("../models/course.model");

const addStudent = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const { name, nic, age, courseId } = ctx.request.body;
    const student
     = await Student.create({
      name,
      nic,
      age,
      courseId,
    });

    await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(courseId, { $push: { students: student._id } });
    return (ctx.body = student);
  } catch (error) {
    return (ctx.body = { message: error.message });
  }
};

const getStudents = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const students = await Student.find().populate({
      path: "courseId",
      select: "courseName courseFee",
    });
    return (ctx.body = students);
  } catch (error) {
    return (ctx.body = { message: error.message });
  }
};

const updateStudent = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const studentId = ctx.params.studentId;
    const { name, nic, age, courseId } = ctx.request.body;

    const student = await Student.findByIdAndUpdate(studentId, {
      name,
      nic,
      age,
      courseId,
    });

    await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(student.courseId, {
      $pull: { students: studentId },
    });

    await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(courseId, {
      $push: { students: studentId },
    });

    return (ctx.body = student);
  } catch (error) {
    return (ctx.body = { message: error.message });
  }
};

const deleteStudent = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const studentId = ctx.params.studentId;

    const student = await Student.findById(studentId);

    await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(student.courseId, { $pull: { students: studentId } });
    await Student.findByIdAndDelete(studentId);
    return (ctx.body = student);
  } catch (error) {
    return (ctx.body = { message: error.message });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  addStudent,
  getStudents,
  updateStudent,
  deleteStudent,
};
```

**course.controller.js**

```
const Course = require("../models/course.model");

const addCourse = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const { courseName, courseFee, students } = ctx.request.body;

    const course = await Course.create({
      courseName: courseName,
      courseFee: courseFee,
      students: students,
    });

    return (ctx.body = course);
  } catch (error) {
    return (ctx.body = { message: error.message });
  }
};

const getCourses = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const courses = await Course.find({}).populate({ path: "students", select: "name nic age" });
    return (ctx.body = courses);
  } catch (error) {
    return (ctx.body = { message: error.message });
  }
};

const updateCourse = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const courseId = ctx.params.courseId;

    const { courseName, courseFee, students } = ctx.request.body;
    const course = await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(courseId, {
      courseName: courseName,
      courseFee: courseFee,
      students: students,
    });
    return (ctx.body = course);
  } catch (error) {
    return (ctx.body = { message: error.message });
  }
};

const deleteCourse = async (ctx) => {
  try {
    const courseId = ctx.params.courseId;
    const course = await Course.findByIdAndDelete(courseId);
    return (ctx.body = course);
  } catch (error) {
    return (ctx.body = { message: error.message });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  addCourse,
  getCourses,
  updateCourse,
  deleteCourse,
};
```

**React App**

**Course.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const CoursePage = () => {
  const [courseName, setCourseName] = useState("");
  const [courseFee, setCourseFee] = useState("");
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);
  const [isEditClick, setIsEditClick] = useState(false);
  const [editId, setEditId] = useState("");

  const [editName, setEditName] = useState("");
  const [editFee, setEditFee] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/course/`).then((res) => {
      setCourses(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const saveData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const courseObj = {
      courseName,
      courseFee,
    };

    axios
      .post(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/course/add`, courseObj)
      .then((res) => {
        alert("Data added");
        axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/course/`).then((res) => {
          setCourses(res.data);
        });
        setCourseName("");
        setCourseFee("");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      });
  };

  const updateData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const courseObj = {
      courseName: editName,
      courseFee: editFee,
    };
    console.log(courseObj);

    axios
      .put(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/course/${editId}`, courseObj)
      .then((res) => {
        alert("Course Updated");
        axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/course/`).then((res) => {
          setCourses(res.data);
        });
        setIsEditClick(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      });
  };

  const deleteCourse = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .delete(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/course/${e.target.id}`)
      .then(() => {
        axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/course/`).then((res) => {
          setCourses(res.data);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      });
  };

  const onEditClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setEditId(e.target.id);
    setIsEditClick(!isEditClick);

    const course = courses.find((course) => course._id === e.target.id);
    setEditName(course.courseName);
    setEditFee(course.courseFee);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Course Page</h1>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter course name"
          value={courseName}
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          onChange={(e) => setCourseName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter course free"
          value={courseFee}
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          onChange={(e) => setCourseFee(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={(e) => saveData(e)} style={{ margin: 5 }}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <br />

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Course Fee</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
          {courses &&
            courses.length > 0 &&
            courses.map((course, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                  {isEditClick && course._id === editId ? (
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={editName}
                      onChange={(e) => setEditName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    course.courseName
                  )}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {isEditClick && course._id === editId ? (
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      value={editFee}
                      onChange={(e) => setEditFee(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    course.courseFee
                  )}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button id={course._id} onClick={(e) => onEditClick(e)}>
                    {isEditClick && course._id === editId ? "Cancel" : "Update"}
                  </button>
                  {isEditClick && course._id === editId && (
                    <button onClick={(e) => updateData(e)}>Save</button>
                  )}
                  <button id={course._id} onClick={(e) => deleteCourse(e)}>
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CoursePage;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="student">
        <button>Manage Students</button>
      </Link>
      <Link to="course">
        <button>Manage Courses</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Student.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const StudentPage = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [nic, setNIC] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [courseId, setCourseId] = useState("");
  const [editStudentId, setEditStudentId] = useState("");


  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

  const [isEditClick, setIsEditClick] = useState(false);
  const [editName, setEditName] = useState("");
  const [editNIC, setEditNIC] = useState("");
  const [editAge, setEditAge] = useState("");
  const [editCourseId, setEditCourseId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/course/`).then((res) => {
      setCourses(res.data);
    });
    axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/student/`).then((res) => {
      setStudents(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

 
  const addStudent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const studentObj = {
      name,
      nic,
      age,
      courseId
    }

        axios
      .post(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/student/add`, studentObj)
      .then((res) => {
        alert("Data added");
        axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/student/`).then((res) => {
          setStudents(res.data);
        });
        setName("");
        setNIC("");
        setAge("");
        setCourseId("");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      });

  };

  const updateStudent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        const studentObj = {
          name: editName,
          nic: editNIC,
          age: editAge,
          courseId: editCourseId
    };
    console.log(studentObj);

    axios
      .put(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/student/${editStudentId}`, studentObj)
      .then((res) => {
        alert("Student Updated");
        axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/student/`).then((res) => {
          setStudents(res.data);
        });
        setIsEditClick(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      });
  };

  const deleteStudent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .delete(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/student/${e.target.id}`)
      .then(() => {
        axios.get(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/student/`).then((res) => {
          setStudents(res.data);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      });
  };

  const onEditClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setEditStudentId(e.target.id);
    setIsEditClick(!isEditClick);

    const student = students.find((student) => {
      student._id === e.target.id;
    });
    if (student) {
      setEditName(student.name);
      setEditAge(student.age);
      setEditNIC(student.nic);
      setIsEditClick(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Student Page</h1>
      <div style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter name"
          value={name}
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter nic"
          value={nic}
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          onChange={(e) => setNIC(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter age"
          value={age}
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
        />
        <select onChange={(e) => setCourseId(e.target.value)}>
          {courses &&
            courses.length > 0 &&
            courses.map((course, index) => (
              <option value={course._id} key={index}>
                {course.courseName}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <button onClick={(e) => addStudent(e)} style={{ margin: 5 }}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>NIC</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Course</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        {students &&
          students.length > 0 &&
          students.map((student, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>
                 {isEditClick && student._id === editId ? (
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={editName}
                      onChange={(e) => setEditName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    student.name
                  )}
              </td>
              <td>
                  {isEditClick && student._id === editId ? (
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={editNIC}
                      onChange={(e) => setEditNIC(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    student.nic
                  )}
              </td>
              <td>
                 {isEditClick && student._id === editId ? (
                    <input
                      type="Number"
                      value={editNIC}
                      onChange={(e) => setEditAge(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    student.age
                  )}
              </td>
              <td>{student.courseId && student.courseId.courseName}</td>
              <td>
                <button id={student._id} onClick={(e) => onEditClick(e)}>
                    {isEditClick && student._id === editStudentId ? "Cancel" : "Update"}
                  </button>
                  {isEditClick && student._id === editStudentId && (
                    <button onClick={(e) => updateStudent(e)}>Save</button>
                  )}
                  <button id={student._id} onClick={(e) => deleteStudent(e)}>
                    Delete
                  </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StudentPage;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CoursePage from "./pages/Course";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import StudentPage from "./pages/Student";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/student" element={<StudentPage />} />
          <Route path="/course" element={<CoursePage />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```